# swift ios9: Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, ios9, cllocation

I write a easy example for mapView suing swift, but I get the print `Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.`

I add a mapView to viewController and start location. I  also call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` before `startUpdatingLocation()`

I set the Info.plist

[image]

now I set both `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` , it doesn't work.
[image]

Tere is my code, what's wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var mapView: MKMapView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

            let status: CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
            if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {

                if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                } 
            }

            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            self.locationManager = locationManager

        } else {

            print("locationServices disenabled")
        }

        let mapview = MKMapView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        mapview.mapType = .Standard
        mapview.showsUserLocation = true
        mapview.delegate = self
        self.mapView = mapview
        self.view.addSubview(mapview)

    }   
}
```

Comment: I add the string to wrong plist. now it works.

Comment: Ha ha , Accidentally i am doing same :) Thanks for comment

Comment: @rose in order to other users benefit from this question, please mark the answer as correct, and edit your question to tell people that you already solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the warning is telling you are missing one of the  two required Strings into your plist

```
 NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

Comment: I set the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in Info.plist

Comment: you need both, they are required

Comment: I add picture in my question.

Comment: Have anyone found solution??

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

you put let and you already declared like a variable:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
```

use it without "let"